# Using @media to hide content not working in Shopify

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries, device

I am trying to hide a Facebook like button when the browser is resized below a certain width.

I have the following code:

```
@media all and (max-width: 300px) 
{
  .fb-like { float: right; display: none; }
}
```

I have tested this on regular websites however it is not working within Shopify. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I could not reference "fb-like" within css I had to create a separate div to wrap around this before I could edit how it was displayed.